# how to get all documents from couchbase lite dot net

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am new to couchbase and couchbase lite. I am trying to implement sync from couchbase lite to couchbase. I did create few documents in couchbase lite using dot net. But i am not able to get all documents to show in the UI.

It would be a great help if i get any code snippet to get all documents from couchbase lite using dot net.

Sample code i am trying to get the documents.

```
using (var query = QueryBuilder.Select(SelectResult.All())
            .From(DataSource.Database(pat_database)))
            {
                // Run the query
                foreach (var result in query.Execute())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.GetString("id"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Console.Writeline is not showing the id of the document. Kindly help.

Comment: Is it showing anything at all?

Comment: I am getting as an object. But not the id value. result.count() shows the documents count. But i am not getting the value of id.

Comment: When you do `SelectResult.All()` the results will be inside of a dictionary, not at the top level.  So you need to do `GetDictionary(0)` first.  If you select the id directly, you can get it as you have already done.

Comment: Thanks borrrden. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: I am having similar issues. It's an awful API!

Comment: did anyone figure out how to get all documents AND the type for each doc ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer, from @borrrden, is correct:

When you do SelectResult.All() the results will be inside of a dictionary, not at the top level. So you need to do GetDictionary(0) first. If you select the id directly, you can get it as you have already done.